# How can I export Attendee list from Microsoft Teams Live events session using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sap-successfactors

We are hard working to try to use the Microsoft Graph in order to get the Attendee data from a Live session in order to import them into SAP SuccessFactos LMS as a virtual learning session attendees based on API economy connectors (rest).

Do you know how can I extract the callRecord ID (highlighted in bold) from the joinWebUrl in order to use the API method GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/**{id}** ?

If you have any tips to extract the live session ID or other way to export the “AttendeeReport.csv” dynamic/automatic, it will be awesome to advance on our pilot

I research based on this blog https://tomtalks.blog/2020/03/microsoft-teams-call-records-and-session-details-api-public-preview/

Comment: You can subscribe to the [change notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) API and get the call Id 
Please take a look at [List Participants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-list-participants?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) & [Get Participant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) in a call using Graph API

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT I have the same problem as marcelo-casaca. Just have subscibed to the notifications on callRecords changes, and there is no Guest name, only default https://yadi.sk/d/20YXQNHFW4AW2g